# How can I add full fenders to a frame with no braze-ons?

Tags: rain, fenders

I recently picked up a bike I want to ride in Seattle rain, but missed the fact that the frame had no braze-ons for attaching full-coverage fenders. I already have a set of SKS Raceblades, but they only provide partial coverage. Do any manufacturers make full-coverage fenders I could use?

Answer (score 3):

Crud Roadracer Mk2s offer a bit more coverage than raceblades I believe

http://www.crudproducts.com/products/roadracer/roadracer_

Answer (score 3):

I have suspension fork with absolutely no brazeon or eyelets. I have SKS Chromoplastics which I used to attach the normal way to my previous steel fork, which had the eyelets.

These Chromoplastics, if not perfect, have served me very well for some years now (with a lot of off-road abuse).

These fenders are currently being manufactured in an "upgraded" version called Longboard:

http://www.sks-germany.com/?l=en&a=product&r=mudguards&i=10438&LONGBOARD

I solvd the problem  very satisfactorily by passing a ziptie through the safety-clip bolt hole (lower-left part of the image below), and then clamping the metal shafts (which had to be shortened) to the safety-clip, the way they are supposed to be.

I put a patch of used-tube rubber between the safety-clip and the suspension, to avoid paint damage and to improve firmness and dampening eventual noise and vibration.

My suggestion would be to get some aftermarket safety-clips and do the same on the rear part of the bike. And if it is not possible, rubber, zipties and drilled aluminum plates solve a lot of problems.

The safety clip I refer to is this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your bike has classic-style steel rear dropouts, you might try the [Rodriguez Components Universal Fenderizing Object](http://www.rodcycle.com/articles/ufo.html).  It's basically a machined screw and plate set that gives you a secure fender mounting position.  Plus, hand-made in Seattle.

[image]

Otherwise, zip-ties or hose clamps can mount the fender stays to the seatstay and fender brackets to bridge the brakes can be [improvised out of pieces of flat stock](http://www.unc.edu/~alanj/Fender%20mounting.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use cable clamps to attach to the fork arms and seat stays for the fender stays.  If the bike has bosses for center-pivot brakes you can anchor the top of the fender to them.  Without the brake bosses, though, I'm not sure how you'd anchor at the top.