# Attaching rear fenders to a bike without eyelets

Tags: commuter, rack, commuting-bike, fenders

I'm currently commuting by bike and wanted to put a pair of permanent fenders to prepare for the coming winter weather. I ride a Jamis Allegro A2 with a rear luggage rack. I have a photo below of what the rear setup looks like stock and also a few pictures of what my bike looks like. If you zoom in you can see the front does come with an eyelet for a fender. The rear does not. I found an attachment by Portland design works you can put on the axel on on [Amazon](https://a.co/d/h4rhkz5). However, I'm not sure they will give me the correct clearance. The fenders I'd like are [Planet Bikes Cascadia bike fenders - 700c x 35mm](https://www.planetbike.com/cascadia-bike-fenders-700c-x-35mm/). What should I do to get a sturdy mounted set of permanent fenders on my bike? Will I have issues getting it to fit with my luggage rack?

[image: eyelets]

[image: bike1]

[image: bike2]

[image: bike3]

Comment: Would one of the following questions with answers answer this?  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6476/how-can-i-add-full-fenders-to-a-frame-with-no-braze-ons  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36808/how-to-install-rear-rack-fenders-on-a-vintage-road-bike

Comment: All the links to the products that work in those posts are broken

Comment: @Ziggy A bit off-topic, but the "mud flap" on the front fender that you linked to is really not as good as it could be - that flap doesn't go low enough to keep the spray from your front wheel off your feet and legs.  This is what a mudflap that keeps spray off your feet and legs looks like:  https://www.rivbike.com/products/sks-fender-mudflap-long-each  If you fail to keep the spray from the front wheel off your feet and legs, it won't take long in any decent rain for your feet to get soaked to the point water sprays out of whatever you're wearing on your feet with every pedal stroke.

Comment: How much protection do you need? Maybe a plastic bottle cut in half and zip-tied to the rack is good enough?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for sharing your experience. I looked at that website you linked and I'm a bit confused at what that website offers. Is that an after market modification that you attach onto one of the SKS fenders? All the sks fenders don't seem to go that low. How do you utilize that product?

Comment: @Ziggy SKS longboards go really quite low, and use softer plastic at the bottom (I have those on my tourer).  I have SKS commuters on another bike, which are much shorter, and have added [Raw mud flaps](https://rawmudflap.uk/) to them (Raw do custom designs/club colours).  The front mudflap on the SKS longboard is actually too low for its shape - if you ride through water more than about 8cm (3")  deep, it scoops the water and throws it out to the sides, straight at your feet.  A flappier, less scooped mudflap doesn't do that, such as the ones from Raw, or the one I made from an old inner tube

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Options

1. Use rack mounting eyelet (with longer bolt if required). This is usually considered acceptable but not always ideal.
2. Stabilise rear mudguard to rack instead of using mudguard stays
3. Use P-Clamps (often found in automotive applications) correct diameter for frame's seatstays to provide an eyelet to bolt the mudguard stays on to. Mikalor ones are a good example.
4. Use Paul H's method. Unfortunately this information is classified.

Comment: My vote would be for #4. I've done it several times and it works great. If possible, put the fender stays outboard and keep the rack inboard.

Comment: Errr I meant #1 in the comment above

Comment: @PaulH updated accordingly.

Comment: $100 in my venmo and i'll reveal the secrets the rack and fender cabals are hiding from true patriots like yourself ;)

Comment: I tend to use no.1, noting that the rack needs to be securely supported especially if it's carrying a heavy load.  If your mudguard stays are steel, no problem, but if they have plastic fittings on the end, you really want that outside the rack, with a washer under the screw head to spread the extra pressure

Comment: With some mudguards, there is an option 4 here (or should it be 5?): Mount the mudguard to one of the 2 bolts each side where the rack proper meets that unusual lower rack bracket.  You'd need to cut the stays down